# JS If field is empty then it should be entered as 0

Tags: javascript

This is the first time I use JS, I'm trying to validate a form, I'm trying to add a 0 if the a field is left empty

I don't know if that makes sense

```
function check() {

    var x = 0
    var y = 1;

    var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('PB').value);

    console.log(num);

    if (x > num || y < num) {

        alert("Enter 0 or 1 only");

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean *instead of* `return`ing `false` you want to set x (or y repectively) to `0` when they are neither `0` nor `1`?

Comment: Basic if statement to check the length, set the value. Or just do it on the server where all the validation should happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"If field is empty then it should be entered as 0"*

```
function check() {
    var textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
    var value = textbox.value;

    if (value) {
        var rExp = /[a-zA-Z]/;
        if (value.search(rExp) != -1) {
            alert("Enter numbers only");
        } else {
            if (value < 0 || value > 1) {
                alert("Enter 0 or 1 only");
                return false;
            } else {
                alert("You entered: " + value);
            }
        }
    } else {
        value = 0;
        alert("Default value: " + value);
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/648Z2/1/)

Comment: Enter `1px` or `0asdksjadhkjsahdsjhdhasj` and it is valid.

Comment: @epascarello Updated the answer. Is it valid? I might still be missing something.

Comment: basically I have a field that has the format 1 representing ‘true’ or ‘0’ representing ‘false’. and also if the field was left empty or ignored and was submitted them it should show a 0 instead of being blank

Comment: How about using a checkbox? Generally, true/false fields are better represented by checkboxes than textboxes.